# how to modify google assistant pushtotalk like hotword

Tags: python-3.6, raspberry-pi3, gpio, google-assistant-sdk, snowboy

i am currently working on school project the goal is whenever i say 'pi'(machine name) 'sing for me'(google = assistant)
since it would be easy if i use hotword but it is currently unavailable and doesn't support our language

at env/lib/googleassistant/--/pushtotalk.py 457 line

wait_for_user_trigger = not once

```
    while True:

        if wait_for_user_trigger:

            ->#click.pause(info='Press Enter to send a new request...')

            ->time.sleep(1)

        continue_conversation = assistant.assist()

        # wait for user trigger if there is no follow-up turn in

        # the conversation.

        wait_for_user_trigger = not continue_conversation



        # If we only want one conversation, break.

        if once and (not continue_conversation):

            break
```

i changed here(->) so that every time it is on state but i cannot find how to call only if it's name is called
could you help me?

and could you tell me if i work this on (env) how can i import GPIO i need to blink led

Answer (score 0):

I was successful with snowboy.
example here:
https://busy.org/@neavvy/google-assistant-on-raspberry-or-part-3-custom-wake-word